# Difference between extjs object and document object

Tags: extjs

What is the difference (if any) between a standard document object and an extjs object? I mean this: 
Is there a difference between

```
<input type = "button">
```

and  `new Ext.Button()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a difference.  The HTML `<input>` element creates a node in the document's DOM tree, which is accessible in JavaScript using DOM methods.  The `Ext.Button()` constructor creates an ordinary JavaScript object, *not* a DOM object, but it knows how to *create* the DOM object when ExtJS asks it to render itself.

Basically, ExtJS components are wrappers around (possibly multiple) DOM objects, and have a higher-level API compared to working with the DOM tree directly.